# How to determine if the argument passed to a C++ template is a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I wrote a template function

```
    template <class T>
    size_t get_size(T const &vec)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
        {
            std::cout << "pointer" << std::endl;
            return vec->size();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "not pointer" << std::endl;
            return vec.size();
        }
    }
```

which determines the size of either the vec, or first references the underlying data and then calles size upon it. Now I wanted to add the case that vec is actually a shared_pointer. But how can I figure that out? Executing

```
std::shared_ptr<Vector> vec = std::make_shared<Vector>(Vector({1, 2, 3}));
    std::cout << typeid(vec).name() << std::endl;
```

gives me `St10shared_ptrISt6vectorIiSaIiEEE` as an output.

My idea was to somehow destructure the type to access the outermoste layer of the type. In that case I could add a `if else case` using the `is_same` function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: a simpler way would be overload them instead of using `if constexpr`

Comment: Which C++ standard?

Comment: You could use SFINAE or a concept to check if the type is dereferenceable.  My suggestion though is to don't do this.  Just require that `get_size` is passed a vector.  Then your caller just has to do `get_size(*my_pointer_to_vector)` and you don't need to worry about it.  Trying to take any pointer like type wont work with overloads as you'll always be adding overloads.

Comment: questions like this depress me - how to use template magic to see if you are using something yoy probably should not be using in the first place?